# Loop through all possible field selections in Qlikview and export charts

Tags: excel, vba, qlikview

In Qlikview, I have multiple filters. For example lets say 3 filters, with 3 possible selection in each. This would give me a total of 27 possible selections.

I want to write a macro that loops through all these 27 selections and exports the charts present in the report for all these combinations to an excel workbook in 27 different sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use VBScript in QlikView to achieve this, however, QlikView doesn't have an API for automatically exporting images of charts to Excel. However, Stefan Walther has written an excellent set of VBScript methods to assist in exporting charts to Excel, in both image and data formats.

You can find his article and code here: http://www.qlikblog.at/971/qliktip-32-exporting-multiple-objects-single-excel-document/

Whilst the above covers exporting fixed charts to Excel, you also wish to make selections, so I put something together for you below that you can utilise in combination with Stefan's export code:

```
Sub ExportCharts()

set field1Values = ActiveDocument.Fields("<your first field here>").GetPossibleValues
set field2Values = ActiveDocument.Fields("<your second field here>").GetPossibleValues
set field3Values = ActiveDocument.Fields("<your third field here>").GetPossibleValues

chartList = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.GetGraphs

for i = 0 to field1Values.Count - 1
    for j = 0 to field2Values.Count - 1
        for k = 0 to field3Values.Count - 1
            ActiveDocument.ClearAll()
            ActiveDocument.Fields("<your first field here>").Select field1Values.Item(i).Text
            ActiveDocument.Fields("<your second field here>").Select field1Values.Item(j).Text
            ActiveDocument.Fields("<your third field here>").Select field1Values.Item(k).Text

            ' ... export operations here...

        next
    next
next

end Sub
```